# Deploy .NET 5 AWS Lambda with Container Images using CDK: Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, .net-5

I've created a new [.NET 5 AWS Lambda Function using Container Images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-5-aws-lambda-support-with-container-images/) via the Visual Studio Project Template:

[image]

And now I want to deploy the Lambda Function and an ApiGateway using the CDK.

I was able to get it deployed, but when I invoke the method, I get this **error**:

```
❯ iwr https://3l0xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/
Invoke-WebRequest: {"message": "Internal server error"}
```

This is what I have in my Stack:

```cs
public class Dotnet5LambdaStack : Stack
{
    internal Dotnet5LambdaStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
    {
        var dotnet5Lambda = new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Lambda.Function(this, "dotnet5Lambda", new FunctionProps
        {
            Runtime = Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
            // relative to the cdk.json file
            Code = Code.FromAssetImage("src/lambdaNet5"),
            
            Handler = Handler.FROM_IMAGE
        });

        new LambdaRestApi(this, "dotnet5ApiEndpoint", new LambdaRestApiProps
        {
            Handler = dotnet5Lambda
        });
    }
}
```

**How do I fix my CDK Stack code so my Lambda + Api Gateway deploy correctly?**

Comment: Did you check cloudwatch logs for any lambda error messages?

Comment: put a try catch and see the exception details

Comment: @Marcin - yup, needed to check my CloudWatch logs, turns out my Function Handler wasn't defined.  Initially I wasn't sure where to put it as the CDK would error out if I set `FunctionProps.Handler` directly.

Comment: @viveknuna - Didn't try putting a try/catch in my lambda application code.  Normally tha's a good place to start, though I'm guessing with what turned out to be my issue (missing function handler) it wouldn't have helped so much as Lambda didn't even start to execute my function code so the try/catch wouldn't even get hit.

Comment: @PhilipPittle good you solved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realized I could mine my CloudWatch logs to get to the real problem - Lambda wants a function handler defined:

[image]

I was able to pass a `AssetImageCodeProps`, with my handler set in hte `Cmd` property, to the `Code.FromAssetImage` and that got it working.

```cs
internal Dotnet5LambdaStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
{
    var dotnet5Lambda = new Amazon.CDK.AWS.Lambda.Function(this, "dotnet5Lambda", new FunctionProps
    {
        Runtime = Runtime.FROM_IMAGE,
        // relative to the cdk.json file
        Code = Code.FromAssetImage("src/lambdaNet5", new AssetImageCodeProps
        {
            // !!Set Handler Here!! Assembly::Type::Method
            Cmd = new string[]{"lambdaNet5::lambdaNet5.Functions::Get"}
        }),
        
        Handler = Handler.FROM_IMAGE
    });

    new LambdaRestApi(this, "dotnet5ApiEndpoint", new LambdaRestApiProps
    {
        Handler = dotnet5Lambda
    });
}
```

After a deploy:

```sh
❯ iwr https://3l0xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```